# Как найти минимальное/максимальное значение конкретного поля? Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Допустим есть коллекция:

```
 Model:

 {title: lsdmk, price: 3,
  title: ksndk, priceL: 8,
  title: ksndk, priceL: 1,
  title: ksndk, priceL: 9,
  title: ksndk, priceL: 0,
  title: ksndk, priceL: 2}
```

Мне нужно получить только один документ с **минимальным** значением поля price:

```
  {title: ksndk, priceL: 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({ priceL: -1 }).limit(1)
```